# Подкасты на русском о Python?

Tags: python, podcast

Существует несколько замечательных подкастов на русском по JavaScript.
А вот по Python не могу найти. Может плохо ищу?

P.S. В некоторых подкастах питон эпизодически встречается. Например:

- http://sdcast.ksdaemon.ru/2015/03/sdcast-21/
- На Радио-Т изредка встречаются разговоры о Python

P.S.S. Если кто-то из потенциальных авторов подкастов в раздумьях, а нужен ли подкаст по Python, то да, нужен :)

Comment: Тема замечательная, но видимо вас забанят.

Comment: @hardsky: если добавить, что подкасты должны быть широко доступны (неплатные), чтобы спам исключить, то почему бы и здесь список не пособирать. В чём вред от наличия ссылок на текущие и прошлые подкасты по Питону?